XmlSerializer unable to resolve assembly at constructor
I am calling the following constructor:
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Slot>));

and end up with this exception in the log :

Unable to resolve assembly System.Private.CoreLib.XmlSerializers,
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
processorArchitecture=AMD64

I noticed this post but since it's not exactly the same exception, I don't know if that is the same issue.
Using the below code avoid to have the exception so I guess it is the same issue but I would like a confirmation:
var serializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(List<Slot>) })[0];

I was not able to find anything on System.Private.CoreLib.XmlSerializers online.
I also gave a try to the XML Serializer Generator solution but since the code is not looking for myapplication.XmlSerializers I guess it does not help.
Any insight/idea/explanation is more than welcome.
Thanks
EDIT:
here are all the details :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
'System.Private.CoreLib.XmlSerializers, Version=6.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
processorArchitecture=AMD64'. The system cannot find the file
specified.'

Stacktrace:

at
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack
assemblyName, ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly,
StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack
retAssembly)

InnerException is null
Call Stack:

[Managed to Native Transition]


System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, bool throwOnFileNotFound, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)    C#


System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool throwOnFileNotFound, System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext) Line 330  C#


System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) Line 191    C#


System.Private.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(System.Type type, string defaultNamespace, out System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerImplementation contract)   Unknown


System.Private.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(System.Type type, string defaultNamespace) Unknown


System.Private.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(System.Type type)  Unknown


Please provide more info, like which .NET (Core / Framework) version are you using + what platform you are using (Windows. MacOS, Linux) + what is your application type (Xamarin, MAUI, Blazor, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET Core, ....)

The application build in .NET 6.0 and running on windows 10. The main application type is WPF but this specific project build a dll used by the main app.

Can you please [edit] your question to share the full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exceptions, if any?  Often the inner exception will identify the problem when XmlSerializer code generation fails.

@dbc done, hope that help. I added the call stack, just in case.

Try Newtonsoft.Json, I remember there is a XmlSerializer class, or you can just switch to Json

I cannot tell what is going wrong from that traceback.  XmlSerializer works by writing, compiling, linking and loading Dynamically generated assemblies.  The traceback indicates that something previously went wrong during that process and the generated DLL cannot be found.  Is there any chance your %TEMP% directory is full or lacks write permission?  Was there some earlier exception you caught and ignored?

One more question: you have the exception in your log, but is anything actually broken?  Is the exception  caught and handled inside the XmlSerializer constructor, or is it thrown to your code?

@dbc nothing to declare about the %temp%. Indeed the exception is caught and handled by the XmlSerializer constructor and beside the exception nothing is wrong with the behavior of the app. It's just a nasty red line in the log ;)

I end up using the FromTypes solution since I do not plan to used it more than once for this type (from what I read it is causing memory leak otherwise)

@Cervelle - in that case you should simply ignore the exception, it's a known harmless behavior of the XmlSerializer constructor.
